# Material design for "insert image" editor action

Tags: gui-design, material-design, editor

I'm developing an online document editor using Google's Material Design.

The editor has a toolbar with actions such as *Bold*, *Italic* and *Insert Image*.

When tapping on *Insert Image* the user shall be able to choose an image to insert. The image can be selected from one of several sources:

- **Local**: User can choose an image on the local file system, which is then automatically uploaded and attached to the document being edited.
- **Attached**: User can choose an image that is attached to the document. Either because the user uploaded it previously or because someone else uploaded it.
- **Library**: User can choose an image from the underlying repository to which the document belongs.
- **Web**: User can also choose an image from the web (using an integrated Google Image Search feature).

In addition; the user can, optionally, also specify settings for how the image shall be inserted. For example, specifying image position and size.

My first idea for this design was to popup a dialog when the user clicks on the *Insert Image* toolbar button.

That dialog would have one tab for each image source (see above). Each tab would have a search field for filtering images along with some source-specific search options.

However, I just learned that this design may be way to complex for a dialog. The [design spec](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/dialogs.html) says:

> Dialogs present a focused and limited set of actions, which are generally affirmative or dismissive.

One idea for simplifying things could be to have all sources in a single list (no tabs). However, I think it is important to clearly separate these source because the inserted image will behave differently depending on source. For example, web images are more or less just a reference while images from the *library* are managed (workflow, permissions etc) along with the document. This could be solved by visually presenting images from different sources in a distinct manner.

As an alternative to a dialog, I've been thinking that maybe I could present the *Insert Image* action in a navigation drawer (sidebar).

So, my questions are:

1. **Is a dialog appropriate for something like this?**
2. **Is it a bad idea, in general, to have tabs in a dialog?**
3. **Would it be better to use a navigation drawer instead of a dialog for more complex actions such as this?***

Any pointers or ideas on how to go ahead with this design would be appreciated!

Comment: Just wondering if you've had a look at the Material Design frameworks yet: http://superdevresources.com/material-design-web-ui-frameworks/

Comment: Yes. I'm using https://material.angularjs.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before I proceed to answer your questions, let me point you to the part of the spec you quoted, which seemingly deems your dialog too complex:

> Dialogs present a focused and limited set of **actions,** which are
>   generally affirmative or dismissive.

This part of the spec is referring to the action buttons that populate the bottom of the dialog, and when speaking about a focused and limited set of actions, the guide is inferring that the buttons should be affirmative or dismissive in their actions, such as an *Okay* or *Cancel* set of actions.

Moving on, I'm going to try and address your queries to the best of my abilities:

**Is a dialog appropriate for something like this?**

> Dialogs inform users about critical information, require users to make
>   decisions, or encapsulate multiple tasks within a discrete process.
>   Their sudden appearance forces users to stop their current task and
>   refocus on the dialog content.

Given your use case, a dialog is a perfect solution, since it warrants immediate attention once the user taps on the *Insert Image* action, and since it encapsulated the entire image picking process into one clearly defined sheet of material

**Is it a bad idea, in general, to have tabs in a dialog?**
**Would it be better to use a navigation drawer instead of a dialog for more complex actions such as this?**

You definitely wouldn't want to replace a dialog with a navigation drawer entirely, given that a navigation drawer is primarily for top level *navigation*.
However, given your scenario, I'll point you in the direction of the Documents app on Android Lollipop, which uses an always open navigation drawer *within* the dialog on tablets and desktops, and a hidden drawer on mobile. This is a better option, since tabs occupy a significant amount of vertical space, and using them on platforms that have more horizontal space than vertical is a no-brainer. However, tabs would do well for mobile, but since consistency is one of the most important aspects of Material Design, a closed drawer is your best option

[image: Documents app on Android tablets]

Answer (score 1):

First thing I thought of is how would Google do it.. so I opened Quick Office and they don't use either a dialog or a navigation drawer. When you select the "+" on their toolbar you get a [Menu](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/menus.html) with the option to add an image from your library or to take one with your camera (plus other options not image related).

To answer your questions:

1. I would say no. You quote the design guideline itself where it says actions are usually affirmative or dismissive - selecting an image doesn't fit as either of those.
2. This seems like a bad idea. Dialogs are meant to be quick selection - that seems like the opposite of something that has four tabs. Here's what Google [says about tabs](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html):

   > Tabs make it easy to explore and switch between different views or
   >   functional aspects of an app or to browse categorized data sets.
3. Navigation drawer doesn't seem like a great option either. By using the navigation drawer you're implying that you navigate somewhere.. all the user wants to do is quickly add an image.

Last thoughts: Your four options are confusing to me. How are local and library different? Attached to what? If you're using only Google image search, is "Web" an accurate/clear of way of describing it?